# ¿Qué coordina este PERO?

Tags: conjunciones

En `Lila estaba interesada PERO no mucho`¿Qué conjunta **pero**?:
¿dos atributos de ESTABA? o ¿dos oraciones, pero una con elipsis?

Answer (score 3):

`Pero` es una conjunción adversativa que, de acuerdo a la RAE, sirve para

> contraponer a un concepto otro diverso o ampliativo del anterior

En este caso el pero no coordina dos oraciones o cláusulas, ni conjunta "atributos" de *estaba*. **Contrapone** dos conceptos (que no son ni siquiera partículas gramaticales del mismo tipo). Ese `pero` sirve para *matizar* el grado de interés de Lila.

Ese `pero` en cuestión es una conjunción. Compara el uso de distintas conjunciones para matizar el grado de interés de Lila:

> Lila estaba interesada, **pero** no (lo estaba) mucho, en ir a la fiesta.
>
> Lila estaba interesada, **y** mucho, en ir a la fiesta.